# When I update the size of an image multiple times, the previous versions of the image remain

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I am new to javascript and phaser, and am working to design a task.

In this task, I want the size of an image, a circle, to change as a function of the distance of the pointer (cursor) from a designated "home" position. I have managed to accomplish this using update(), however the previous versions of the circle remain after the size of the circle updates, so I get something that looks like this:

[The concentric blue rings show where the previous circles are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SQQy.png)

Here's what I want to have happen:

The cursor is initially set at a designated starting position. The user then moves the cursor to a location on the screen, and after they stop at that location for a given period of time, an image of a red circle is displayed prompting them to move back to the starting position. As the user moves the cursor toward the starting position, I want the circle image to decrease in size. I was able to successfully alter the size of the circle as a function of cursor position using the code below, but, as can be seen in the image above, a new circle is being returned each time I run the chunk without destroying the previous circles.

Here is my code for this:

```
update () {  
      let pointerpoint
      let config = this.game.config
      let user_config = this.game.user_config
      let canvas_height = config.height
      let canvas_width = config.width
      this.cameras.main.setBounds(
        -canvas_width/ 2,
        -canvas_height/ 2,
        canvas_width,
        canvas_height);

      let return_circle = this.add.image(0, 0, 'red').setInteractive()
      return_circle.setVisible(false)
      
      if (state == 'stop') { //defined earlier, state is used to detect whether cursor has been stopped long enough 
        
        const endPoint = {x:end_pos_x, y:end_pos_y}  //final position of cursor      
        const pointer = this.input.activePointer
        const invisible_home = this.add.image(0, tablet_floor, 'home').setInteractive()

        let px = pointer.x - (config.width/2)
        let py = pointer.y - (config.height/2)
          pointerpoint = {x: px, y: py}
    

        let size //size of the circle as a function of cursor position
        size = Phaser.Math.Distance.BetweenPoints(pointerpoint, invisible_home) / Phaser.Math.Distance.BetweenPoints(endPoint, invisible_home)


        return_circle.setScale(size).setVisible(true)
}
```

I expected that by initially setting the circle visibility to "false" (outside the condition state == stop), the "old" circles would disappear with each new update. However, this does not seem to be the case.

Does anyone have suggestions? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just wanted to know if my answer solved your question, or if I missed something. If it solved your issue please consider accepting the answer with the green checkmark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Well the main issue is that you are creating the images in the `update` function, so you are creating about 60 image per second. You actually should create objects in the `create` function and just alter/update there properties in the `update` function. something like this:

```
create(){
    ...
    this.circle = this.add.image(10, 10, 'red-circle');
    ...
}

update(){
    ...
    this.circle.setScale(2);
    ...    
}
```

If you rewrite your code to create the images in the `create` function, and only update the properties in the `update` function, it should work.

That said, phaser has manyyyyyyy helper functions and cool feature that make your life easy.

**Like:**

1. the input handlers, that can handle all the pointer actions like dragging ([link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.60.0/Phaser.Input.Events.DRAG)), and
2. the Math / Vector helper functions ([link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/Phaser.Math.Vector2))

With this you can create your task with less code and pretty simple.

**Here a short demo:**
*(I hope this helps showcase, the aforementioned "features")*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class SampleScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('SampleScene');
    }

    create() {
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'Drag circles to scale them')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({ fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial' });

        // Start -- Make Image for Demo
        let graphics = this.make.graphics();
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFF0000);
        graphics.strokeCircle(10, 10, 9);
        graphics.generateTexture('red-circle', 20, 20);
        // End -- Make Image for Demo

        // create the game object
        this.imageCircle = this.add.image(150, 90, 'red-circle')
            .setInteractive();
        
        //Extra Phaser Drawn Circle
        this.drawCircle = this.add.ellipse(250, 90, 19, 19)
            .setInteractive();
        this.drawCircle.setStrokeStyle(2.1, 0x00FF00);

        // make the gameobject draggable
        this.input.setDraggable([this.imageCircle, this.drawCircle]);
        // listen to the drag-event
        this.input.on('drag', this.dragImage, this);
        
        
    }

    dragImage(pointer, gameobject) {
        // get the while "Drag"-Vector from the pointer properties
        let dragVector = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(pointer.downX - pointer.x, pointer.downY - pointer.y);
        // "Math.max" and "/ 10" is only used to keep the scaling easy for the demo
        gameobject.setScale(Math.max(dragVector.length() / 10, 1));
    }
}

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: SampleScene,
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> **btw.:** You could even draw circles with phaser ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Ellipse.html)), this would look better when you have to scale.